# Angular 1.2.10 - Breeze - .Net 4.5 - File Upload with form

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, file-upload

```
             Hi All,
```

My environment : Angular 1.2.10 - Breeze - .Net - Entity-Framework ADO .Net 6.0

I've seen a lot of posts for file upload (alone) such as https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload
I'm trying to upload a file within all of a form, but without success.

Would you have any idea ?

I'm doing mvvm on angular-side, it gives :

Angular - html :

```
<section id="register-view" class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="register as vm">
    <form name="RegisterForm" ng-submit="submit()" data-n ng-controller="vm.Ctrl">
        <section class="matter">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="today-datas">
                            <li class="blightblue">
                                <div class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></div>
                                <div class="datas-text pull-right">
                                    <span class="bold">11, 12, 13 Février 2014<br />Microsoft Techdays, France</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="widget wviolet">
                            <div data-cc-widget-header title="{{vm.title}}"
                                 allow-collapse="true"></div>
                            <div class="widget-content text-center text-info">
                                <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Nom utilisateur</td>
                                            <td><input ng-model="vm.user.UserName" required /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Mot de passe</td>
                                            <td><input ng-model="vm.user.Membership.Password" required type="password" /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Confirmation mot de passe</td>
                                            <td><input ng-model="vm.user.Membership.ConfirmPassword" required type="password" /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Photo <strong>(facultatif)</strong></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <!--<input ng-model="vm.user.Photo" type="file" />-->
                                                <div ng-controller="vm.CtrlPhoto">
                                                    <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" />
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<div id="dropbox" class="dropbox" ng-class="dropClass"><span>Drop files here...</span></div>-->
                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Prénom</td>
                                            <td><input ng-model="vm.user.FirstName" required /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Nom</td>
                                            <td><input ng-model="vm.user.LastName" required /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Email</td>
                                            <td><input ng-model="vm.user.Membership.Email" required type="email" /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Téléphone <strong>(facultatif)</strong></td>
                                            <td><input ng-model="vm.user.Phone" type="tel" /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Date de naissance <strong>(facultatif)</strong></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <!--<input ng-model="vm.user.Phone" type="tel" />-->
                                                <select>
                                                    <option value="0"></option>
                                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                                    <option value="23">23</option>
                                                    <option value="24">24</option>
                                                    <option value="25">25</option>
                                                    <option value="26">26</option>
                                                    <option value="27">27</option>
                                                    <option value="28">28</option>
                                                    <option value="29">29</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <select>
                                                    <option value="1">Janvier</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Février</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Mars</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Avril</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Mai</option>
                                                    <option value="6">Juin</option>
                                                    <option value="7">Juillet</option>
                                                    <option value="8">Août</option>
                                                    <option value="9">Septembre</option>
                                                    <option value="10">Octobre</option>
                                                    <option value="11">Novembre</option>
                                                    <option value="12">Décembre</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Position</td>
                                            <td><textarea ng-model="vm.user.Position" wrap="hard" rows="5" cols="60" /></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Intérêts</td>
                                            <td><textarea ng-model="vm.user.Interests" rows="5" cols="60" /></td>
                                            <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget-foot">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </form>
</section>
```

The js viewModel :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'register';
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', 'entityManagerFactory', register]);

    function register(common, datacontext, entityManagerFactory) {
        var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
        var log = getLogFn(controllerId);

        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Register';
        vm.Ctrl = Ctrl;
        vm.CtrlPhoto = CtrlPhoto;

        var user = {
            ApplicationId: "1",
            UserId: "",
            UserName: "",
            LoweredUserName: "",
            MobileAlias: "",
            IsAnonymous: false,
            LastActivityDate: "",
            FirstName: "",
            LastName: "",
            BirthDate: "",
            CountryCode: "",
            Phone: "",
            Photo: "",
            PathPhoto: "",
            Position: "",
            Interests: "",
            Application: "",
            Membership: {
                ApplicationId: "1",
                UserId: "",
                Password: "",
                PasswordFormat: "",
                PasswordSalt: "",
                MobilePIN: "",
                Email: "",
                LoweredEmail: "",
                PasswordQuestion: "",
                PasswordAnswer: "",
                IsApproved: "",
                IsLockedOut: "",
                CreateDate: "",
                LastLoginDate: "",
                LastPasswordChangedDate: "",
                LastLockoutDate: "",
                FailedPasswordAttemptCount: "",
                FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart: "",
                FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount: "",
                FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart: "",
                Comment: "",
                Application: "",
                User: ""
            },
            Missions: "",
            PersonalizationPerUsers: "",
            Profile: "",
            WebpagesOAuthMemberships: "",
            Roles: "",
            PostedFile: ""
        };
        vm.user = user;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            common.activateController(null, controllerId)
                .then(function () {
                    log('Activated Register View');
                });
        }

        function CtrlPhoto($scope) {
            $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
                //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
                for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
                    var file = $files[i];
                    vm.user.PostedFile = file;
                    //$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                    //    url: '/IdPhoto', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
                    //    // method: POST or PUT,
                    //    // headers: {'headerKey': 'headerValue'},
                    //    // withCredential: true,
                    //    data: vm.myModelObj,
                    //    file: file,
                    //    // file: $files, //upload multiple files, this feature only works in HTML5 FromData browsers
                    //    /* set file formData name for 'Content-Desposition' header. Default: 'file' */
                    //    //fileFormDataName: myFile, //OR for HTML5 multiple upload only a list: ['name1', 'name2', ...]
                    //    /* customize how data is added to formData. See #40#issuecomment-28612000 for example */
                    //    //formDataAppender: function(formData, key, val){} //#40#issuecomment-28612000
                    //}).progress(function (evt) {
                    //    console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                    //}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    //    // file is uploaded successfully
                    //    console.log(data);
                    //});
                    //.error(...)
                    //.then(success, error, progress); 
                }
            }
        }

        function Ctrl($scope) {
            $scope.submit = function () {
                //vm.user.Photo = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
                datacontext.Register(vm.user)
                            //.then(loadFile($upload))
                            .then(common.logger.log("File posted"))
                            .catch(failCallback)

                //$upload.upload({
                //    url: '~/IdPhoto',
                //    file: vm.user.PathPhoto // for single file
                //})
                //.then(function (data) {
                //    vm.user.PathPhoto.fileId = data;
                //})
            };
            function loadFile($upload) {
                //var fd = new FormData();
                var fileToUpload = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
                //fd.append("uploadedFile", fileToUpload);

                //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                //xhr.open("POST", '/IdPhoto');
                //xhr.send(fd)



                $upload.upload({
                    url: '/IdPhoto',
                    file: fileToUpload,
                }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    //console.log(data);
                }).catch(failCallback(error));

            }
        }

        function failCallback(error) {
            var msg = 'Error Posting File ' + error.message;
            common.logger.logError(msg, error);
            throw error;
        }

    }
})();
```

By the ApiController - BreezeController side the post method gives:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
//[HttpPost]
public string Register(User user)
{
    System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status = MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
    //pour les nouvelles inscriptions il n'y a pas de nwpassword et de confirmnewpassword
    //ModelState.Remove("user.Membership.NewPassword");
    //ModelState.Remove("user.Membership.ConfirmNewPassword");

    //if (ModelState.IsValid)
    //{
        // Tentative d'inscription de l'utilisateur
        try
        {
            CVAppMembershipProvider provider = (CVAppMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Providers["CVAppMembershipProvider"];
            var httpContext = (HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
            var foo = httpContext.Request.Form["Foo"];


            MembershipUser usr = provider.CreateUser(user, out status);

            if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                  usr.UserName,
                  DateTime.Now,
                  DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                  false,
                  "", //userData
                  FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

                ////Encrypt the ticket.
                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
                //create and set cookie in response
                var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1);
                cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
                cookie.Path = "/";
                resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(status.ToString(), GetErrorMessage(status));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
        }
    //}

    return status.ToString();

}
```

In this post method I would like to do some treatments on the user (JSon Format) spent by the viewModel, this is OK. 
In the same time I would like to upload the file from the form (element 'fileToUpload' from the angular form). Is it possible ?

All the examples found over internet don't give an answer.

I suppose the Json format for serialization is not able to spend the file.

XML serialization would help ?

Any simpler solution ?

Thanx in advance for your help

Comment: This is not a Breeze question as Breeze is not involved in any pertinent way. That is why I have removed the Breeze tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
It consists to do only the UploadFile, to spend the user to the UploadFile (change the name ==> Register), it gives in the datacontext (javascript) :

```
function Register($upload, user, postedFile) {
    return $q.when(
                    $upload.upload({
                        url: 'CVApp/User/Register', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
                        method: 'POST',
                        // headers: {'headerKey': 'headerValue'},
                        // withCredential: true,
                        data: user,
                        file: postedFile,
                        // file: $files, //upload multiple files, this feature only works in HTML5 FromData browsers
                        /* set file formData name for 'Content-Desposition' header. Default: 'file' */
                        //fileFormDataName: myFile, //OR for HTML5 multiple upload only a list: ['name1', 'name2', ...]
                        /* customize how data is added to formData. See #40#issuecomment-28612000 for example */
                        //formDataAppender: function(formData, key, val){} //#40#issuecomment-28612000
                    }
                )
                .then(successCallback)
                .catch(failCallback)     // same as 'then(null, failCallback)'
                .finally(finalCallback) // sort of like 'then(finalCallback, finalCallback)'
    );
}
```

on the server-side, it gives in the ApiController :

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/IdPhoto");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try
    {
        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        User user = new User(provider.FormData);

        System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status = MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
        CVAppMembershipProvider mProvider = (CVAppMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Providers["CVAppMembershipProvider"];

        MembershipUser usr = mProvider.CreateUser(user, out status);

        if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
              usr.UserName,
              DateTime.Now,
              DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
              false,
              "", //userData
              FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            ////Encrypt the ticket.
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
            //create and set cookie in response
            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1);
            cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Path = "/";
            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(status.ToString() + " - " + GetErrorMessage(status));
        }

        // This illustrates how to get the file names.
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            string fileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
            if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
            }
            if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            }

            fileName = user.UserName.Replace(" ", "_") + "." + fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf(".") + 1);

            File.Copy(file.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(root, fileName));
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Et voilà ! It works.

Now I just need to have the "BusyIndicator" while processing, to have the error / right message at the end, and also to be able to execute my async methods in the order I want (if it's possible, I thought the "then" could do this), I'm still searching, I suppose I'll find this fastly on Internet.

Thanx